# Recover libreoffice file in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, data-recovery

I have Lubuntu and I write document with libreoffice (6.3.2.2) during the last 2 weeks, the file size was around 100-130 kB.

During this time I saves this document and shutdown my pc few time.

Today, when I tried to open this document, I saw the file size is 9 kB, and I got error

```
Some errors were encountered during the import.
```

How can I recover my document?

Comment: I personally would stop using your system, boot a "live" system & `fsck` your disk (ie. file system check of your partition(s)).  It may not be necessary, but you could be looking at a symptom of something and that file difference is your warning.  If errors are found & fixed; your issue may have been fixed. I wouldthen boot normally,  go to terminal and look at what files are present (ie. navigate to the file directory and look there, I'd also `stat` and `file` them to see if the type so file are correct.  I'd then `cp` (copy) them & work on trying to re-load the copies to get your data back.

Comment: I would view the contents of the files (is the data all there, how does the content of file compare with other .odf like formatted files compare; does it look normal - if there is a difference you have something to work with). etc. etc. I'd hope to see details at any step I'd mention that may change my direction, or provide new things to track down.. My thoughts anyway on what I'd do... (*there may be better as I rarely use libreoffice*)

Comment: According to [this similar situation](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/recovering-word-documents-please-help.310660/), you may be able to open the document using a text editor like vim, nano or gedit. Using a text editor, you may be able to recover the text portion of the document. You may be able to at least copy and paste the missing text from the text editor into a new libreoffice document (**using a different filename, of course,** to retain the original as a backup).

Comment: If the file contains a bunch of useless code. I believe Gedit has a find and replace function that you can use to clean it up and get rid of that stuff.